# Using JSON Path in Spark SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jsonpath

While working with nested JSON in Spark SQL, can JSON path be used to extract data from JSON?

Ex:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

To select authors where book category is reference using json path, I can use `$.store.book[?(@.category == 'reference')].author`.

Is it possible to define a Spark table using such operations?

Comment: If I understand your question well, I'd say that you'll need to filter using the absolute path.

Comment: @eliasah Sorry, didn't understand the solution you hinted. A small example based on the json in question will help clarify.

Comment: I meant to use something like $"`store.book.category`" === "fiction" par example

Comment: I didn't find any acceptable solution for this. 
I looked for _get_json_object()_ function but it does not do the trick as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way of using JSONPath to do what you want, but here is how I would do it:

1. explode the array,
2. query on the records.

Note that you do not have to explode the entire array.

Code:

```
package net.jgp.books.sparkInAction.ch12.lab920QueryOnJson;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

/**
 * Using JSONpath-like in SQL queries.
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class QueryOnJsonApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    QueryOnJsonApp app = new QueryOnJsonApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Query on a JSON doc")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

    // Reads a JSON, stores it in a dataframe
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
        .format("json")
        .option("multiline", true)
        .load("data/json/store.json");

    // Explode the array
    df = df
        .withColumn("items", functions.explode(df.col("store.book")));

    // Creates a view so I can use SQL
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("books");
    Dataset<Row> authorsOfReferenceBookDf =
        spark.sql("SELECT items.author FROM books WHERE items.category = 'reference'");
    authorsOfReferenceBookDf.show(false);
  }
}
```

I think it's a great question, I added it to chapter 12 of [Spark in Action](https://jgp.net/sia).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Applying a sql selection is one thing and that's not the point here. Imagine the json is nested with 40 levels.

Comment: Where is the JSONPath in the answer?

Comment: I never pretended I would use JSONPath, it's Spark, it's not MongoDB ;)...

Comment: Not that, but it's the question of the OP and every one ending up here, including me. Objectively, the answer is interesting but not useful for the posed problem. It's a whole different solution to access a data source using ad hoc declarative query language than to reproduce the same effect imperatively using Spark code. PS: JSONPath is an independent language that can Spark implement if it wants to. It's also Spark and not MySQL, but there is a whole library called Spark SQL.

Comment: In Databricks SQL you can do it but not in Spark SQL.  

See here: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/colonsign.html

Comment: can advanced filter expressions like  $.store.book[?(@.category == 'reference')].author ... to select authors where book category is reference , be also be possible in Databricks SQL ? documentation doesn't give any examples explicitly for this capability

Answer (score 0):

spark does offer the [get_json_object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#get_json_object) function, which can access JSON bodies by JSONPath, which should work in the same way as you desire it.

of course, if you want to implicitly generate a table from a given JSON body, exploding or flattening might be the easier way, although you lose control over the schema - that is, if the JSON has additional keys in some rows, your schema will get wider. using a list of keys you want to extract and store in columns via `get_json_object` will be cleaner for a production use case.